# Trying to use shorten the text output using truncate smarty tag in PHP 5.4.19

Tags: truncate, php-5.4

trying to use `{$articleTitle|truncate:30:""}` to shorten the text output

its working in localhost correctly
but not working in server with `PHP 5.4.19` 
am unable to find solution.
I think there is no problem with code problem in server.
any suggestions plz.

error info.

Fatal error! Your request can not be executed!

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function mb_substr() in Smarty/plugins/modifier.truncate.php on line **36**

Comment: finally i corrected the issue by installing mbstring in my server.

Comment: Error message explained need to check extension was installed in the first place